# Spark write DataFrame out jdbc error

Tags: scala, jdbc, apache-spark

I would like to write the prediction result DataFrame back to oracle database like this way:
    model.transform(testDate).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(url,"b_spark_tst",prop)

but I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>
```

Can anyone help me how to write out DataFrames to database?

Thank you!

update:

this is how my DataFrame schema looks like:

```
root
 |-- CATEG: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COMM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)
 |-- words: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- rawPrediction: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- probability: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How defined your table which you'are keen to overwrite ? And how looks like schema structure of data frame ?

Comment: updated with the schema structure. i think words column will be the problem. I haven't created my table in the db yet.. should I? :)

Comment: if i modify my code : model.transform(testDate).select("CATEG" , "COMM" , "label" , "fatures" , "rawPrediction" , "probability" , "prediction").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url,"b_spark_tst",prop) i get not seen label exception.. :(

Comment: try just one column, creating and appending to existing table providing outcome as comment here.

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "KALLER_USR"."B_SPARK_TST"."COMM" (actual: 291, maximum: 255 how can it happen?? i create already the table with varchar(4000) columns

Comment: What is the version of Oracle 11/12 ?

Comment: it's oracle XE i think it's 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129436/discussion-between-faigb-and-solarenqu).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and it is related to the way you are trying to save the element field inside words field Array. One solution is to save that array as a String.

In my case I have:

```
 |-- jurisdiction_names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

What I am doing using pyspark is

```
newDataFrame = completeDataFrame.select("jurisdiction_names")
```

and I am getting

```
+--------------------+
|  jurisdiction_names|
+--------------------+
|             [Paris]|
|         [Amsterdam]|
|      [Santa Monica]|
|[DISTRICT OF COLU...|
|             [Paris]|
|[Illinois State, ...|
+--------------------+
```

With a new dataframe you can manipulate the info easily.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy can you please check this and provide solution -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151363/not-able-to-write-spark-dataset-to-database-using-jdbc

Comment: @CodeRunner: Don't ping folks asking for help with a particular question. If they can help, they will probably see it anyway, and won't appreciate being bugged. (Pinging a random *editor* is even worse: I don't know anything about Spark so I couldn't give you the slightest bit of help even if I wanted to.)