# Not able to write spark dataset to database using jdbc

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark-sql

I need to write my spark dataset to oracle database table. I am using dataset write method with append mode. But getting analysis exception,
when the spark job was triggered on cluster using spark2-submit command.

I have read the json file, flattened it and set into a dataset as abcDataset.

Spark Version - 2 
Oracle Database 
JDBC Driver - oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Programming Language - Java

```
Dataset<Row> abcDataset= dataframe.select(col('abc').....{and other columns};


Properties dbProperties = new Properties();
            InputStream is = SparkReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dbProperties.yaml");
            dbProperties.load(is);
            String jdbcUrl = dbProperties.getProperty("jdbcUrl");
            dbProperties.put("driver","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String where = "USER123.PERSON";
            abcDataset.write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource").option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").mode("append").jdbc(jdbcUrl, where, dbProperties);
```

Expected - to write into database but getting the error below -

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Multiple sources found for jdbc (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource), please specify the fully qualified class name.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:670)
```

Do we need to set any additional property in spark submit command, as i am running this on cluster, or any step is missing ?

Comment: The json is read is into a dataset  properly printed when its show function was called. Also, the json is flattened properly without any errors. Only when we are selecting few columns and trying to save into the database, it does not work out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either abcDataset.write.jdbc or abcDataset.write.format("jdbc") when you are writing via jdbc from spark to rdbms.

Comment: if you check the below file :- 
/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala

  private val backwardCompatibilityMap: Map[String, String] = {
    val jdbc = classOf[JdbcRelationProvider].getCanonicalName

Map(
      "org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc" -> jdbc,
      "org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.DefaultSource" -> jdbc,
      "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource" -> jdbc,
      "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc" -> jdbc,
      "spark.sql.json" -> json,
   
we have to maintain the jdbc jar , and there are many, so how to make it unique